# why draggable elements aren't responding to snap options when snap object is being shown and hidden during draggable events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Don't know if the title is clear enough, but I wanted to make a draggable element snap to a few guides that are hidden in the first place, when i start dragging the element, they are shown... but the element doesn't snap to them... it's like, it doesn't recognizes it around it.... why is it?

I Made this Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cLs7mq4p/

Code is really simple

```
$(".block").draggable(
    {
        snap: ".guide",
        snapTolerance: 10,
        //grid: [10,10],
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(".guide").show();
        },
        stop: function( event, ui) {
            $(".guide").hide();
        }
    });
```

Where the HTML is like this;

```
<div class="h-line guide" style="top: 100px"></div>
<div class="h-line guide" style="top: 400px"></div>
<div class="v-line guide" style="left: 80px"></div>
<div class="v-line guide" style="left: 400px"></div>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got helped by Jquery UI since it was a bug and this feature was never asked by any other person before... so this is an alternative to make it work :)

By using the on mousedown event.

```
$(".block").draggable({
    snap: ".guide",
    snapTolerance: 10,
    stop: function( event, ui) {
        $(".h-line").css("display", "none");
    }
}).on( "mousedown", function() {
    $(".h-line").css("display", "block");
});
```

Here's the fixed JSFiddle by jQUery UI Support and the comment they made:

> Hi msqar, Thanks for taking the time to contribute to jQuery UI You
>   can get the behavior you're looking for by using a mousedown listener
>   so that the showing/hiding occurs before draggable's snap logic runs: 
>   http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/cLs7mq4p/2/. This isn't something we
>   intend to add support for in the library as the snap option is not
>   being preserved in the draggable widget rewrite. Also this behavioris
>   something no one has asked for before.

Hope it works for other people too :)